# Escape Eventlistener doesn't work but when i put enter in it, it works?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keypress, event-listener

My Eventlistener for "Escape" doesn't work, but if I put in "Enter" instead of "Escape" it works with "Enter".

Here is my Code:

```js
addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
  if (event.key === "Escape") {
    spanClick();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the "Escape" key is not detected by the `keypress` event. The `keypress` event is generally used for character keys only and not special keys. Use the `keydown` or `keyup` event instead.